# How to use ng-repeat with ng-model and get an ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with `ng-model="award.myProperty"`. There are some inputs and texareas. In my service I have an array for textareas:

```
 allQuestions = [
    id: 'XXX', question: 'some text',
    id: 'YYY', question: 'some text', 
    id: 'ZZZ', question: 'some text',
 ];
```

My goal is to get data from textareas in such structure

```
questions: [{
   'XXX': 'data from textarea1',
   'YYY': 'data from texarea2',
   'ZZZ': 'data from textarea3',
}];
```

I've tried to use ng-repeat with `ng-model`, but `ng-model` doesn't return ID's. If I use `$index` with `ng-repeat` then I get an array:

```
[{ 0: 'data from textarea1',
   1: 'data from textarea2',
   2: 'data from textarea3',}]
```

Structure is good, but that's not my ID's from service.

*SERVICE*

```
const allQuestions = [
   { id: 'XXX', question: 'question1' },
   { id: 'YYY', question: 'question2' },
   { id: 'ZZZ', question: 'question3' },
];

getQuestion() {
  return allQuestions;
},
```

*CONTROLLER*

```
$scope.allQuestions = awards_service.getQuestion();
$scope.award = {
    description: '',
    questions: [],
};
```

*VIEW*

```
<form name="awardForm">
    <input ng-model="award.description"></input>
    <div ng-repeat="question in allQuestions">
        <textarea ng-model="award.questions"></textarea>
   </div>        
</form>
```

Maybe there is a better solution than `ng-repeat`.

Comment: What is your goal? To display something or get data in a specific structure?

Comment: @John to get specific structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller change `$scopre.award.questions` to:

```
$scope.allQuestions = awards_service.getQuestion();
$scope.award = {
    description: '',
    questions: [{}]
};
```

Then in the view:

```
<form name="awardForm">
    <input ng-model="award.description"></input>
    <div ng-repeat="question in allQuestions">
        <textarea ng-model="award.questions[0][question.id]"></textarea>
   </div>        
</form>
```

**Demo:**

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller('myCtrl', ['awards_service', '$scope', function(awards_service, $scope) {
  $scope.allQuestions = awards_service.getQuestion();
  $scope.award = {
      description: '',
      questions: [{}],
  };
  
  $scope.submit = function() {
    console.log($scope.award);
    // submit your form then reset the award object
    // ...
    $scope.award = {
        description: '',
        questions: [{}],
    };
  }
}])
.factory('awards_service', function() {
  const allQuestions = [
     { id: 'XXX', question: 'question1' },
     { id: 'YYY', question: 'question2' },
     { id: 'ZZZ', question: 'question3' },
  ];

  return {
    getQuestion() {
      return allQuestions;
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { height: 70px !important; overflow: auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <form name="awardForm" ng-submit="submit()">
    <label>Description</label><br>
    <input ng-model="award.description"></input><br>
    <label>Questions</label><br>
    <div ng-repeat="question in allQuestions">
        <textarea ng-model="award.questions[0][question.id]" placeholder="Enter a question"> </textarea>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: fixed the problem

Comment: how can I fix that my ng-model copies in textarea on page load? I need to see a placeholder, but I have a text inside the field

Comment: and one more thing, when i submit my form once, next time it sends an object again. How can I change that and always send an array?

Comment: @OlegShchegolev I've updated the answer and added a demo